# Convert qint64 to QString

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qstring, qtcore

With other types I could easily do something like

```
mitm.created().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Is there a similar function to turn a qint64 into a QString? You can find the code below.

```
    fileArray.append("[");
    foreach(QFileInfo mitm, mDir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files)){
        fileArray.append("{\"filePath\": \"");
        fileArray.append(mitm.absoluteFilePath());
        fileArray.append("\",");
        fileArray.append("\"fileCreated\": \"");
        fileArray.append(mitm.created().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        fileArray.append("',");
        fileArray.append("'fileSize': '");
//      fileArray.append(mitm.size());
        fileArray.append("\"}");
        if(fileCount!=mDir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files).count()-1){ fileArray.append(","); }
        fileCount++;
    }
    fileArray.append("]");
```

I've commented out the line which breaks the code. I had the same problem with date but used toString to convert it. I was hoping there would be a similar solution for qint64.

Comment: Are you trying to convert it to a date string, or get a string representation of the number?

Comment: I'm trying to convert it into a string which contains file size. I'm not sure how to apply the suggested answers to my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to write the following code for that:

```
fileArray.append("[");
foreach(QFileInfo mitm, mDir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files)){
    fileArray.append("{\"filePath\": \"");
    fileArray.append(mitm.absoluteFilePath());
    fileArray.append("\",");
    fileArray.append("\"fileCreated\": \"");
    fileArray.append(mitm.created().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    fileArray.append("',");
    fileArray.append("'fileSize': '");
    fileArray.append(QString::number(mitm.size()));
    fileArray.append("\"}");
    if(fileCount!=mDir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files).count()-1){ fileArray.append(","); }
    fileCount++;
}
fileArray.append("]");
```

See the documentation of the `QString::number(...)` static methods for details, starting [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qstring.html#number). You will need the variant matching qint64 which is the qlonglong override.

Answer (score 17):

You are probably looking for [`QString::number(qlonglong, int)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number-6).

Answer (score 6):

More general reply, because a lot of people gets here trying to find the answer to the exact question in the title:

```
QDateTime lm = QFileInfo(QFile(current)).lastModified();
qint64 epoch = lm.toMSecsSinceEpoch();
QString str = QString::number(epoch); // actual conversion
```